# Mailcow sieve script that removes attachments and adds a message to the body

Tags: email, email-attachments, sieve

I'm trying to find out how to remove non-whitelisted attachments (by mime type) (f.e. zip, exe, ...)
and append a message about the removed attachments.

I found this: https://superuser.com/a/1502589
And it worked to add a message to the subject.
But I cannot find out how to add a message to the body.

My plan was to use a regex on the attachment mime types and allow f.e.
`text/*` and `application/json` etc.
But I cannot find a single example how to change the body.

I'm using mailcow and sieve script (which I'm both new to).
Or is there a better way to "sanitize" emails before the get put into the inbox?

**EDIT** *(2023-02-07)* : I found this today:
Extension `foreverypart`.

> Sieve Email Filtering: MIME Part Tests, Iteration, Extraction, Replacement, and Enclosure

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5703.html \

> The "replace" command is defined to allow a MIME part to be replaced
> with the text supplied in the command.

Exactly what I try to do.
Now I need to find out how to install the extension and try it out.

Comment: dovecot/pigeonhole sieve only support part of RFC5703 see [here](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/sieve/pigeonhole_sieve_interpreter/#supported-features), and my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76435794/482519